# XAML StringFormat to format a Double value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to format my slider value to be 00:00 format. The below code worked for me, but what I wanted is 00:00 format. I am looking for a total XAML solution. I know that I can write a converter for this easily but wonder if there are any StringFormat way to make it.

```
Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider,StringFormat=\{0:00.00\}}"
```

My question here is how can I get colon ':' instead of dot '.' ?

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to put a `:` symbol in the format string, then you escape it with backslashes:

```
Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider,StringFormat=\{0:00\\:00\}}"
```

But I think this is what you want to do:

```
<Slider Name="slider" Width="500" Height="30" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider, StringFormat={}{0:00\\:00}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default String formatting options in the StringFormat as in regular C# code. Have a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), you'll probably find what you need.

Comment: thanks, but I know that I can use any of the String format expressions.. But coudlnt get a solution for colon ':' Since double value formatting is expecting a dot '.' somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a real solution to this but if you can multiply your slider values by 100 you can just use 00:00 as your format string.